# Is there a way to render a Map as an HTML table in Grails?

Tags: grails

I was wondering if there was a nice way to render a `Map` to an HTML table within a `.gsp` page.

An example `Map`:

```
def map = ['Mammals':['Unicorn','Chimpanzee','Goat'],
                   'Reptiles':['Snake','Turtle']];
```

This would render to something like this:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Mammals</th>
      <th>Reptiles</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Unicorn</td>
      <td>Snake</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Chimpanzee</td>
      <td>Turtle</td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Goat</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Ideally I could then create my own custom tag, so I could do this:

```
<stackOverflow:tablizer map="${map}" />
```

Comment: You will have to create your own tag. Shouldn't be that hard.

Comment: @JamesKleeh  right-o!  I was looking for some help with the impl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this - Probably a better way to do it, but this was what I came up with first.

```
def mapToTable = { attrs ->

StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder()

if ( attrs.map instanceof Map )
{ 
    Map map = attrs.map

    if ( map.size() > 0 )
    {
        output.append("<table><thead><tr>")

        ArrayList[] values = map.values()

        int max = values.collect{it.size()}.max()


        map.each { key, val ->
            output.append("<th>${key}</th>")
        }

        output.append("</tr></thead><tbody>")

        (1..max).each { num ->
            output.append("<tr>")

            values.each {

                if ( it.size() >= num  )
                {
                    output.append("<td>${it.get(num-1)}</td>")    
                }
                else
                {
                    output.append("<td></td>")   
                }
            }    

            output.append("</tr>")
        }

        output.append("</tbody></table>")
    }

}
out << output
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on @James Kleeh's answer, but I modified his code to print a list of Maps, such as what you get back from Groovy Sql results:

```
protected String mapToTable(List<Map> list) {

    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder()

    Map first = list.first()

    output.append("<table><thead><tr>")

    first.each { key, val ->
        output.append("<th>${key}</th>")
    }

    output.append("</tr></thead><tbody>")

    list.each { map ->
        if (map.size() > 0) {

            def values = map.values()

            output.append("<tr>")

            values.each {
                output.append "<td>${it}</td>"
            }

            output.append("</tr>")
        }
    }
    output.append("</tbody></table>")

    output.toString()
}
```